# Get first and last row from result in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

```
   public function get_task_threads_first_last($task_id)
   {
      $this->db->select("t.nt_id, t.nt_responsed_by, t.nt_detail 'task_detail',       t.nt_response_date, u.ui_full_name 'user_name', u.ui_designation 'user_designation', u.ui_phone 'extension', nt_response_date 'response_date'");
      $this->db->from('tm_task_detail t');
      $this->db->order_by("nt_response_date");
      $this->db->join('ac_user_info u', 'u.ui_id = t.nt_responsed_by');
      $this->db->where('t.nt_task_id', $task_id);
      $query = $this->db->get();
      return $result = $query->result();
   }
```

I need to fetch the first and last row from above query. How is this possible ?

Also i am thinking that it is useless to select all rows than get the first and last rows out from it. I'm new in programming need advice thanks.

Thanks

Comment: write two separate queries which ORDER BY ASC and ORDER BY DESC with LIMIT 1

Comment: @PravinS can't it be done with a single query by supplying something to where clause ?

Comment: You can achieve this by using UNION operator. But UNION is not supported by codeigniter active record. So you can directly write the query using UNION operator